# How to generate a random string in PHP (using 3 strings and random numbers)

Tags: php, string, random

I have three strings and i want to generate a random string **using those 3 strings** with **including some random number** between the strings.

Thank You

```
Ex: first string : john
    second string : smith
    third string : john9k

    I want a random string like : john.simth190, smith.john9k, john9k.123.smith, etc.,
```

How to do this in PHP.

Thank You

Comment: `rand()` will give you random numbers and dot (`.`) performs string concatenation, e.g. `echo 'john' . rand(1, 1000) . '.smith';` might yield `john271.smith`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php 
function random($items, $min=0, $max=100, $random_parts=2, $delimiter="."){
    #make sure items is an array
    $items = (array)$items;        

    #add as many random bits as required.
    for($x=0; $x<$random_parts; $x++)
          $items[] = rand($min, $max);

    #shuffle and join them
    shuffle($items);
    return implode($delimiter, $items);
}
```

Basically what it does is accept an array of the names, array('john','smith','john9k'). Then it takes the min rand and the max rand parameters. Finally it accepts the amount of random numbers you want.

So to call It i'd do this:

```
<?php
echo random(array('john','smith','john9k'), 0, 100, rand(0,10));
```

Comment: That's pretty good, but I think it'd be a random byte in this case, rather than a random bit.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it to be random parts, rather then bits or bytes. Couldn't think of the word but thanks for mentioning it, i've updated it

Comment: @Jason: Very Good Logic and implementation. Thank You. But i am getting an error at implode function Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: @Jason: I got it. we have to shuffle the array outside the implode function. shuffle($items); and then implode($delimiter, $items);

Comment: oh yeah, shuffle returns a bool, not the modified array.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this too

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]].$input[$rand_keys[1]].rand(0,100);
```